# Processing and editing youtube video in place with chrome extension?

Tags: image-processing, google-chrome-extension, video-processing, youtube-javascript-api

I am looking to make a chrome extension that analyzes frames of a youtube video being watched and overlays a rectangle around certain points of interest.

Is there any api to access the frames being rendered and preprocess them in real time?

If this isn't possible my next idea would be to download the video separately(either locally or on a backend server) processing and storing the needed coordinates and then overlaying the rectangles as an html/js animation? Ideally using some sort of buffering system so the entire video doesn't need to be preprocessed before playing.

Are either of these possible, or is there a better solution that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Extensions can use [tabCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) but I think writing an external utility (launched via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)) might provide much more flexibility and performance.

Comment: Thanks! tabCapture seems like it could work, however I am not clear on the benefit of an external utility?

Comment: An external utility can use powerful video-processing libraries and whatnot.